# Import pfx file into particular certificate store from command line

Tags: powershell, certificate, certutil

It's relatively easy to import a certificate into the user's personal store from a pfx file by using CertUtil:

```
certutil –f –p [certificate_password] –importpfx C:\[certificate_path_and_name].pfx
```

But this ends up in the Personal Store of the current user. I need it in TrustedPeople on  LocalMachine.

Is there any way I can do this from the command line, either by calling different arguments on certutil importpfx, using another certutil command or a different utility? Powershell is another possibility, although I don't know much about it.

Cheers,
Matt

Answer (score 73, accepted):

Anchoring my findings here for future readers.

Import certificate to Trusted Root Certification Authorities on Local Machine:

```
CERTUTIL -addstore -enterprise -f -v root "somCertificat.cer"
```

Import pfx to Personal on local machine

```
CERTUTIL -f -p somePassword -importpfx "somePfx.pfx"
```

Import pfx to Trusted People on local machine - [Link](http://home.fnal.gov/%7Ejklemenc/importpfx.html) to importpfx.exe

```
importpfx.exe -f "somePfx.pfx" -p "somePassword" -t MACHINE -s "TRUSTEDPEOPLE"
```

Import certificate to Trusted People on local machine

```
Certutil -addstore -f "TRUSTEDPEOPLE" "someCertificate.cer"
```

Comment: It is frustrating that CERTUTIL cannot import a PFX to TRUSTEDPEOPLE. CertUtil works fine with a remote PSSession (PowerShell), but importpfx does not (FYI, source to importpfx is http://home.fnal.gov/~jklemenc/src/importpfx.cpp). I'm not sure what CERTUTIL is doing differently, but it *does* work with remote PS sessions, but I cannot place the cert in Trusted People. Sigh. A very frustrating couple of days.

Comment: We ended up writing a set of powershell functions, to do the hard work. Look at CiPsLib.Certificates.psm1 -> Import-Certificate https://github.com/rasmus/CiPsLib/tree/master/tools

Comment: How can i import without using a password? Is it possible?

Comment: @drgmak, if the certificate is protected with an empty password you use -p "". If it is password protected you need to know the password.

Answer (score 9):

To anyone else looking for this, I wasn't able to use `certutil -importpfx` into a specific store, and I didn't want to download the importpfx tool supplied by jaspernygaard's answer in order to avoid the requirement of copying the file to a large number of servers. I ended up finding my answer in a powershell script shown [here](http://forums.iis.net/t/1180871.aspx?SSL%20certificate%20importing%20to%20wrong%20certificate%20store).

The code uses `System.Security.Cryptography.X509Certificates` to import the certificate and then moves it into the desired store:

```
function Import-PfxCertificate { 

    param([String]$certPath,[String]$certRootStore = "localmachine",[String]$certStore = "My",$pfxPass = $null) 
    $pfx = new-object System.Security.Cryptography.X509Certificates.X509Certificate2 

    if ($pfxPass -eq $null) 
    {
        $pfxPass = read-host "Password" -assecurestring
    } 

    $pfx.import($certPath,$pfxPass,"Exportable,PersistKeySet") 
    
    $store = new-object System.Security.Cryptography.X509Certificates.X509Store($certStore,$certRootStore) 
    $store.open("MaxAllowed") 
    $store.add($pfx) 
    $store.close() 
}
```

Comment: can you please help me understand values and its meaning. "MaxAllowed", "My",

Comment: @RaviKhambhati: My is the name of the cert store I'm using. see https://msdn.microsoft.com/en-us/library/windows/desktop/aa388136(v=vs.85).aspx for some more info about cert store locations.
MaxAllowed is the value of the OpenFlags I am using to open. I honestly just copied and pasted that part, but you can learn more about it's possible values here: https://msdn.microsoft.com/en-us/library/system.security.cryptography.x509certificates.openflags(v=vs.110).aspx

Comment: Thanks a lot. When we do the same operation from IIS what will be these values

Comment: Your code is literally **wrong**. You're using non-ASCII `“`, which cause undefined behavior in powershell. It may randomly fail, on randomly line, with random reason, in the farking unreliable powershell parser.

Comment: I've adjusted it @recolic. I'm not sure if that worked in my environment or if I had fixed it but forgot to come update this answer.

Answer (score 6):

Check these links:
http://www.orcsweb.com/blog/james/powershell-ing-on-windows-server-how-to-import-certificates-using-powershell/

Import-Certificate: http://poshcode.org/1937

You can do something like:

```
dir -Path C:\Certs -Filter *.cer | Import-Certificate -CertFile $_ -StoreNames AuthRoot, Root -LocalMachine -Verbose
```

Answer (score 5):

For Windows 10:

Import certificate to Trusted Root Certification Authorities for Current User:

```
certutil -f -user -p certPassword -importpfx root "example.pfx"
```

Import certificate to Trusted People for Current User:

```
certutil -f -user -p certPassword -importpfx TrustedPeople "example.pfx"
```

Import certificate to Trusted Root Certification Authorities on Local Machine:

```
certutil -f -user -p certPassword -enterprise -importpfx root "example.pfx"
```

Import certificate to Trusted People on Local Machine:

```
certutil -f -user -p certPassword -enterprise -importpfx TrustedPeople "example.pfx"
```

Comment: I was really struggling to add a user certificate to a new store.  The last example worked for me.  Note: if you use a store name (e.g. "ABC") instead of "TrustedPeople" the store will be created!  There is no need to use the -addstore argument to add a store...this is the thing that I was stuck on.

Answer (score 3):

With Windows 2012 R2 (Win 8.1) and up, you also have the "official" [Import-PfxCertificate cmdlet](https://technet.microsoft.com/en-us/library/hh848625%28v=wps.630%29.aspx)

Here are some essential parts of code (an adaptable example):

```
Invoke-Command -ComputerName $Computer -ScriptBlock {
        param(
            [string] $CertFileName,
            [string] $CertRootStore,
            [string] $CertStore,
            [string] $X509Flags,
            $PfxPass)
        $CertPath = "$Env:SystemRoot\$CertFileName"
        $Pfx = New-Object System.Security.Cryptography.X509Certificates.X509Certificate2
        # Flags to send in are documented here: https://msdn.microsoft.com/en-us/library/system.security.cryptography.x509certificates.x509keystorageflags%28v=vs.110%29.aspx
        $Pfx.Import($CertPath, $PfxPass, $X509Flags) #"Exportable,PersistKeySet")
        $Store = New-Object -TypeName System.Security.Cryptography.X509Certificates.X509Store -ArgumentList $CertStore, $CertRootStore
        $Store.Open("MaxAllowed")
        $Store.Add($Pfx)
        if ($?)
        {
            "${Env:ComputerName}: Successfully added certificate."
        }
        else
        {
            "${Env:ComputerName}: Failed to add certificate! $($Error[0].ToString() -replace '[\r\n]+', ' ')"
        }
        $Store.Close()
        Remove-Item -LiteralPath $CertPath
    } -ArgumentList $TempCertFileName, $CertRootStore, $CertStore, $X509Flags, $Password
```

Based on mao47's code and some research, I wrote up a little article and a simple cmdlet for importing/pushing PFX certificates to remote computers.

[Here's](http://www.powershelladmin.com/wiki/Import_PFX_certificates_on_remote_servers_%28PSv2-compatible%29) my article with more details and complete code that also works with PSv2 (default on Server 2008 R2 / Windows 7), so long as you have SMB enabled and administrative share access.

Comment: Whilst this may theoretically answer the question, [it would be preferable](//meta.stackoverflow.com/q/8259) to include the essential parts of the answer here, and provide the link for reference.

Answer (score 1):

Here is the complete code, import pfx, add iis website, add ssl binding:

```
$SiteName = "MySite"
$HostName = "localhost"
$CertificatePassword = '1234'
$SiteFolder = Join-Path -Path 'C:\inetpub\wwwroot' -ChildPath $SiteName
$certPath = 'c:\cert.pfx'


Write-Host 'Import pfx certificate' $certPath
$certRootStore = “LocalMachine”
$certStore = "My"
$pfx = New-Object System.Security.Cryptography.X509Certificates.X509Certificate2
$pfx.Import($certPath,$CertificatePassword,"Exportable,PersistKeySet") 
$store = New-Object System.Security.Cryptography.X509Certificates.X509Store($certStore,$certRootStore) 
$store.Open('ReadWrite')
$store.Add($pfx) 
$store.Close() 
$certThumbprint = $pfx.Thumbprint


Write-Host 'Add website' $SiteName
New-WebSite -Name $SiteName -PhysicalPath $SiteFolder -Force
$IISSite = "IIS:\Sites\$SiteName"
Set-ItemProperty $IISSite -name  Bindings -value @{protocol="https";bindingInformation="*:443:$HostName"}
if($applicationPool) { Set-ItemProperty $IISSite -name  ApplicationPool -value $IISApplicationPool }


Write-Host 'Bind certificate with Thumbprint' $certThumbprint
$obj = get-webconfiguration "//sites/site[@name='$SiteName']"
$binding = $obj.bindings.Collection[0]
$method = $binding.Methods["AddSslCertificate"]
$methodInstance = $method.CreateInstance()
$methodInstance.Input.SetAttributeValue("certificateHash", $certThumbprint)
$methodInstance.Input.SetAttributeValue("certificateStoreName", $certStore)
$methodInstance.Execute()
```

Comment: You probably want the import flags to be `"Exportable,MachineKeySet,PersistKeySet"` in order to get the private key into the machinekeys, rather than into the current users' profile.

Answer (score 0):

In newer version of windows the Certuil has [CertificateStoreName] where we can give the store name. In earlier version windows this was not possible.

Installing *.pfx certificate: 
certutil -f -p "" -enterprise -importpfx root ""

Installing *.cer certificate: 
certutil -addstore -enterprise -f -v root ""

For more details below command can be executed in windows cmd.
C:>certutil -importpfx -?
Usage:
  CertUtil [Options] -importPFX [CertificateStoreName] PFXFile [Modifiers]